# Syntax Highlighting for .gitignore in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know of one?  Question in title.

Comment: I used this plugin to have vim assert some colors on the gitignore files: https://github.com/fszymanski/fzf-gitignore  It turns asterisks blue, square brackets brown and slashes purple and projects some highlighting around typical gitignore expressions.  Another one here: https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=5183

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this syntax highlighting by installing the [Fugitive plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) I believe. And if that doesn't do it you can install [this syntax file](https://github.com/tpope/vim-git). Both by tpope, excellent additions to your Vim arsenal. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It seems that my Vim install already does .gitignore highlighting, I just put the .gitignore in the wrong place.  Will leave your answer up for others who have this problem though.